# "What do ...have not to worry about?" vs. "...have to not worry about?"

Tags: word-order, negation

Is it correct to ask:

> What do people living in intelligent homes **have not to worry about**?

or:

> What do people living in intelligent homes **not have to worry about**?

Answer (score 2):

Setting aside the issue of intelligent homes, the usual construction is **what do people have to worry about** or **what do people not have to worry about.**

Regarding your first example, it's possible to imagine a context in which somebody says:

> There are so many things that I have to worry about right now.

To which someone else might respond:

> What do you have not to worry about.

It's a play on words asking: **What is it you have that you are not worried about?**

But it's not typical.

So while both of your constructions are possible, the second is idiomatic and far more likely in most contexts.